# Cooking eggs too soon for Keto dough

Tags: eggs, dough, low-carb, keto

I've recently been looking at Keto recipes and Fathead dough came up. The recipe specifies that I should be careful to not cook the egg before you put the dough in the oven. It was really difficult to get the egg to mix into the melted cheese, almond flour mix. I'm wondering why I shouldn't just mix the egg in with the almond flour and cheese before melting the cheese?

Fathead recipe: https://www.ditchthecarbs.com/fat-head-pizza/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I love Fathead dough!*

No, don't microwave the egg. If the temp gets up to about 145°F, the proteins in an egg will solidify and you'll end up with bits of scrambled eggs smushed into the pizza crust. Unless that's your thing, I wouldn't microwave the egg.

But...you are right. It can be hard to mix the cheese(s) and flour together and then to incorporate the egg into that mixture.  So...the real secret is to just use your hands to mix it all together. It's messy but well worth it.

Comment: *However, I don't follow the recipe exactly. I leave out the cream cheese (personal preference). And I usually don't do the second, 30-second microwaving. If the dough were to cool too much, I might do 10-15 more seconds, but otherwise I just immediately start mixing the egg in (so I have it already broken in a bowl with the rosemary and/or other seasoning for speed). 

I always cook it on one side for about 8 minutes and then flip it and finish baking of the crust. Only then do I add toppings (already cooked) and bake a final few minutes until the cheese topping is nicely melted.