# Fat Head Dough Optimum Thickness

Tags: dough, keto

I saw [Cooking eggs too soon for Keto dough](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/85357/6279) earlier this week and determined this "**[Fathead Dough](https://www.ditchthecarbs.com/fat-head-pizza/)**" was something to be tried. How thick should the 'dough' be rolled, particularly for 'other applications' (taco bowls and nacho chips in particular)

Answer (score 1):

Both thicker and thinner can work as long as you roll it out **evenly**.

In my experience, rolling it thinner makes it feel more like "real" wheat dough. However that way it feels more like flatbread than proper pizza crust.